# new columns in index created inside for loop

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, indexing

I am trying to create something that measures up days and down days in stocks as measured by a higher or lower close than the day before. This is displayed as a 1 for an 'up day' and a -1 for a 'down day'. I am OK with this part.

I would like some help/explanation about how to run this function over multiple stocks, so that I end up with an array of each stock in different columns and each day in different rows.

Ideally with the dates in the initial column.

This is what I have so far for generating individual stocks. I have tried some *args and for loops of tickers into the function, but haven't got anything meaningful out of it.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas.io.data
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

ticker = 'aapl'
begin = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1)
finish = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 15)

# Start Workings
def adcount (begin, finish,ticker):
    dat = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=begin,  end=finish)
    close = dat.columns[3]
    close1 = np.ma.fix_invalid(dat[close].shift(1))
    close0 = dat[close].shift(0)
    count = 0
    for f, b in zip(close1, close0):
        if b > f:
            count = 1
        else:
            count = -1
        print count
adcount(begin,finish,ticker)
```

Much thanks in advance for any help / ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can do the sign calculation against the series directly with `numpy.sign` rather than iterating through each item.  This is based on the Yahoo sample from Pandas 0.13 docs.  If you're using an older version, you may need to tweak it to work with that version.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
from datetime import datetime as dt

def get_stock_data(ticker, start, end):
    return web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)

def get_returns(stock_history):
    base = stock_history['Close']
    shifted = base.shift(1)
    return (base - shifted)[1:]

start = dt(2013, 1, 1)
end = dt(2013, 1, 15)

tickers = ['AAPL', 'XOM', 'MMM']

data = {}
for t in tickers:
    history = get_stock_data(t, start, end)
    data[t] = get_returns(history).apply(np.sign)

print(pd.DataFrame(data))

>>>         AAPL  MMM  XOM
Date                      
2013-01-03    -1   -1   -1
2013-01-04    -1    1    1
2013-01-07    -1    1   -1
2013-01-08     1    1    1
2013-01-09    -1    1   -1
2013-01-10     1    1    1
2013-01-11    -1   -1    1
2013-01-14    -1    1   -1
2013-01-15    -1    1   -1
```

Comment: Hey, not sure whats going on, I can only get it working when it runs two tickers, not three or more. Getting an IOError: after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url.    any ideas?  also on line 22 replaced ticker with t.

Comment: Yahoo doesn't want to return a result for GOOG today for some reason.  I changed the example to use MMM instead, and I was able to pull data for all three.

Comment: Not sure I follow you.